# How to locate the element using Selenium Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver, webdriverwait

```
<input name="txtAnswer" class="box1" id="txtAnswer" type="text" maxlength="20">
```

My code:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("txtAnswer")).sendKeys("green");
```

Comment: formatting required to make this more readable

Comment: First of all please provide us more information, there is no error message in this question and before sendKey() method try to click that element. Try sendKeys after clicking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To locate the desired element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#txtAnswer[class^='box'][name='txtAnswer']")).sendKeys("green")
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[starts-with(@class, 'box') and @id='txtAnswer'][@name='txtAnswer']")).sendKeys("green")
  ```

---

### Update

As you are seeing the error *Unable to locate element* you need to induce *WebDruverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input#txtAnswer[class^='box'][name='txtAnswer']"))).sendKeys("green")
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[starts-with(@class, 'box') and @id='txtAnswer'][@name='txtAnswer']"))).sendKeys("green")
  ```

Comment: thanks for replay, but it also view error message Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[starts-with(@class, 'box') and @id='txtAnswer'][@name='txtAnswer']"}
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.86)

Comment: thanks for you support, but also get same error (Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.cssSelector: input#txtAnswer[class^='box'][name='txtAnswer'] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:95)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:272)
 at Demo.TasheelIE.main(TasheelIE.java:46)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == input#txtAnswer[class^='box'][name='txtAnswer'])

Answer (score 0):

Id and class are two attributes for an web-element. to identify web element uniquely(one)  id is used and to identify web elements use common properties like class, tag name etc..
so writing xpath with id attribute will give you unique match.

Answer: driver.findElement(By.id("txtAnswer")).sendKeys("green");